# redefining array push method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm newbie in js.
I redefined push() method in Array Object like below..

```
Array.prototype.push = function(item) {
    this[this.length] = '[' + item + ']';
    return this;
};

var arr = new Array();
arr.push('my');
console.debug(arr);
console.debug(arr[0]);

arr.push('name');
console.debug(arr);
console.debug(arr[1]);

arr.push('is');
console.debug(arr);
console.debug(arr[2]);


// output

[] --> <1>
[my]
[] --> <2>
[name]
[] --> <3>
[is]
```

but I can't understand why <1>,<2>,<3> is empty.

Comment: Are you debugging in chrome by any chance? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the brackets being concatenated, it works.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ekCdR/).

[It looks like](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/aYVrL/) `push` is called internally a bit, and this may be why it is not working.

Also, there shouldn't be any reason to re-implement `push` yourself.

Comment: I too noticed this. Extremely odd behavior.

Comment: it appears to happen only in webkit browsers.

Comment: This does not seem to be the case for me.  I justed tested in Chromium 10.0.648.133 (Linux) and the issue is still prevalent.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `console.debug(arr.join(','));` instead of `console.debug(arr);`.

As in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbhvB/).

The output is now

```
[my]
[my]
[my],[name]
[name]
[my],[name],[is]
[is]
```

Tested on Chrome.

As for the strange behavior of `debug.console()` when printing arrays, I suspect that it also uses push() on arrays while building the output string.  If, for example, you replace the `'['+item+']'` with `'<<'+item+'>>'` you get some whackiness in the Firebug console, as in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QN3Gv/).

Comment: This is a very informative post and most definitely the answer.  Chrome Tools wackiness.